# Certificados SSL gratuito Let’s Encrypt tem a mesma confiabilidade dos pagos?

Tags: ssl, certificado-digital

**Encriptografia** `TLS` é a utilizada pela `lets encrypt` e usa o protocolo `acme` que faz a troca de arquivos entre servidor - cliente, percebo que ao utilizar `https` os sites ficam com um pequeno `delay` já utilizei o certificado pago e também percebi esse delay, com base nisso creio que deva ser pelo fato da troca dos arquivos onde ele é `criptografado` transferido e checado e `descriptografado`.

**Minha dúvida** é a seguinte, estou pesquisando sobre certificados SSL e me deparo com muitos fóruns comentando sobre o certificado Let’s Encrypt, que são muito bons e gratuitos mas não consegui descobrir a confiabilidade dos mesmos, e se podem ser utilizados em ecommerce com a mesma segurança que os certificados pagos?

**Ou como desenvolvedor** devo utilizar estes certificados apenas para testar as aplicações, e quando houver a homologação do cliente devo fazer a contratação?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Os certificados oferecidos atualmente no mercado são tão baratos que, particularmente falando, não compensa a "economia" com alternativas gratuitas. Mas independente disso, o  Let’s Encrypt atualmente possui um amplo suporte e é reconhecido pelos principais ambientes web (browsers). Porém ainda incompatível em outros ambientes em determinadas circunstâncias. O uso vale mais a pena onde você tem um projeto de teste onde não pretende gastar 1 centavo e não tenha muita preocupação com a compatibilidade.

No entanto, para uma loja virtual, mesmo que pequena, não é uma boa escolha. Dadas as condições e opções existentes no mercado.

Eu preferiria não citar nomes de certificadoras mas, como a própria pergunta menciona nomes, posso citar o GlobeSSL que oferece certificados de 3 anos por 20USD. Esse valor é praticamente de "graça" comparando até mesmo com os menores preços do RapidSSL (85 USD / 3 anos). Note que há certificados cujo preço "normal" é de 250USD / ano. Os certificados da GlobeSSL são da COMODO, altamente confiáveis e recomendados pelas certificadoras.

Por quê mencionei que não é uma boa optar por alternativa gratuita para uma loja virtual? É simplesmente pelo que já foi explicado acima referente ao leque de compatibilidades e por existir opções acessíveis para baixo orçamento.

Se a loja virtual não consegue pagar 20 dólares trianual é porque está falida.

Todavia, nada impede de que utilize alternativas gratuitas como o Let's Encrypt.

Um informação pertinente, comentada pelo @Inkeliz, é que os certificados do Let's Encrypt possuem um prazo de vida curto. Atualmente é de 90 dias (3 meses).

Para resolver esse pequeno problema é possível criar scripts para auto renovação do certificado. Isso pode ser feito por conta própria rodando em background (cron / schtask) ou utilizar o [certbot](https://github.com/certbot/certbot).

Num resumo geral, ao escolher uma emissora de certificados, verifique os pontos básicos:

**- Confiabilidade perante os browsers**
 
Não existe 100% de compatibiliadde em nenhum certificado, desde o gratuito ao mais caro. Porém, normalmente os que são estáveis anunciam compatibilidade de 99.9%.

**- Assinaturas e encriptação**
 
O mínimo, porém não obrigatório, aceitável atualmente é de assinaturas de 2048 bits e encriptação 254 bits.

**- Limitações de licensas por servidor**
 
Atualmente é comum não existir limitações. Exemplo, você comprou um certificado para um domínio, porém, possui um site com 15 servidores. Antigamente havia restrições por exemplo, limite de até 5 ou 10 servidores então teria que comprar 2 ou 3 certificados para um mesmo domínio.

**- Logo/marca para aumentar taxas de conversão SEO.**
   
Isso é algo importante para aumentar a confiabilidade do seu site perante os visitantes e também aos motores de busca.

**- Garantias** (indenização)
   
Um certificado pago normalmente oferece planos de garantia variados. Por exemplo, se um certificado falhar causando danos ao proprietário e for comprovado que a falha é do emissor do certificado, o proprietário recebe um valor de indenização. Esse valor normalmente é de 50 mil dólares em diante. É normal que os valores ultrapassem 2 milhões de dólares, por exemplo.

Esses pontos básicos não são claros no site oficial do Let's Encrypt. Obviamente porque não garantem. E por ser gratuito não há opção de garantia contra falhas. Pois o termo de garantia nada mais é que um seguro de indenizações. Você paga isso embutido no valor do certificado.

Comment: +1 Pelos preços. Só para acrescentar a comodo tem ~50 dólares, anual, um certificado "Wildcard", que abrange subdomínios. Um detalhe, o Let's Encrypt ainda tem o "problema" de ser limitado em até 90 dias o certificado (https://letsencrypt.org/2015/11/09/why-90-days.html).

Comment: Atualizando, atualmente não existem mais os certificados de 3 anos. O padrão foi modificado para 2 anos em Maio ou Março de 2018. Não entendi por quê tantos negativos. Gostaria de saber o que escrevi que pode estar errado...